# How to extract a percentage column from a periodic column and the sum of the column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform, percentage

I have a matrix that looks like this in as `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
  Store Sales   year  month day
0   1   5263    2015    7   31
1   1   5020    2015    7   30
2   1   4782    2015    7   29
3   2   5011    2015    7   28
4   2   6102    2015    7   27
[986159 rows x 5 columns]
```

After I do some transformation I get the total sales sum for each shop:

```
train['StoreTotalSales'] = train.groupby('Store')['Sales'].transform('sum')
```

But now I need to iterate through each row of `train.groupby(['Store', 'day', 'month'])` and then divide the `Sales` figure of each row of the groupby and divide by the `StoreTotalSales`.

I've tried the following:

```
train['PercentSales'] = train.groupby(['Store','day', 'month'])['Sales'].transform(lambda x: x /float(x.sum()))
```

But it's return all 1s for the new `PercentSales` column:

```
  Store Sales   year  month day StoreTotalSales PercentSales
0   1   5263    2015    7   31  26178                1
1   1   5020    2015    7   30  26178                1
2   1   4782    2015    7   29  26178                1
3   2   5011    2015    7   28  12357                1
4   2   6102    2015    7   27  12357                1
```

But that's PercentSales row should have been:

```
0    5263/26178
1    5020/26178
2    4782/26178
3    5011/12357
4    6012/12357
```

Comment: why u r not simply doing `train['PercentSales'] = train['Sales'] / train['StoreTotalSales']`?

Comment: Ah yes, that would work. But is there a way to avoid precomputing `train['StoreTotalSales']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the complication of another `groupby`? If all you want is to divide the column by the group sum, you can simply do:

```
train['PercentSales'] = train.groupby('Store')['Sales'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

Or equivalently, following your method:

```
train['StoreTotalSales'] = train.groupby('Store'['Sales'].transform('sum')
train['PercentSales'] = train['Sales']/train['StoreTotalSales']
```

Let me know if you run into additional problems.